# Check if comma separated String contains Integer

Tags: vba

I have a String that separates Integers `"1,4,15,24"`

I want to check if this String contains a specific Integer

E.g. Does it contain `5`? False. Does it contain `15`? True

Is there any one line solution to check for this in Visual Basic? If not, what's the best solution for this?

Comment: Use instr(str,value to be searched) method to check whether the value is present in a string

Comment: I am aware of InStr but that will find '5' inside the String since there is the value '15'. Sure I can look for ',5' but that fails when 5 is in the beginning

Comment: Add an extra comma at start and end of the string during search

Comment: @testus do you need one line solution  to this ?

Comment: Split the string into an array using the comma as a delimiter, then use a loop to test each value - if the value matches then set a boolean to True and exit the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could be strange initially but if you add the comma at the start and at the end of the string, in this way ",1,4,15,24," 
then use instr

```
pos = InStr(",1,4,15,24,5,", ",5,")
```

you can find if the number is present, because you can use the comma as a marker to separe all the items. if pos returns a number different from 0 you have found it.